# SSH service not restart and log file stop logging

Tags: solaris, root, sshd

I am using Solaris (5.11 11.3 i86pc i386 i86pc).
I am trying disable login by root via ssh
I edit  `PermitRootLogin yes` to   `PermitRootLogin no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` then restart ssh service.
I have tried:

```
svcadm disable ssh
svcadm enable ssh
```

or

```
svcadm restart ssh
```

then I check status by this

```
svcs -l svc:/network/ssh:default
```

It seem to be restarted because of changing of property "enabled" true/false
and see logs by

```
cat /var/svc/log/network-ssh:default.log
```

but nothing log anymore just this

```
[ May 14 08:00:07 Enabled. ]
[ May 14 08:00:07 Rereading configuration. ]
[ May 14 15:01:42 Executing start method ("/lib/svc/method/sshd start"). ]
Creating new rsa public/private host key pair
Creating new dsa public/private host key pair
[ May 14 15:01:43 Method "start" exited with status 0. ]
[ May 14 15:23:07 Stopping because service restarting. ]
[ May 14 15:23:07 Executing stop method (:kill). ]
[ May 14 15:23:07 Executing start method ("/lib/svc/method/sshd start"). ]
[ May 14 15:23:07 Method "start" exited with status 0. ]
```

And I still login by root via ssh account. How can I fix that?

Comment: Here is it: `PermitRootLogin no`

Comment: Log file seem to be locked from May 14th.

Comment: When you log in through `ssh` do you get prompted for root's password? (There is a root password on your system, isn't there...?)

Comment: When I log in through `ssh`, It didn't ask anything. (I am using Xshell 6 and Authentication keeping on this session is belong to root account)
I try fix `PermitRootLogin` for other Solaris server (5.11 11.4.21.69.0 i86pc i386 i86pc) just like this and very times I login with root account it always ask for password and still not login althrough It was typed by right password (that is the result I hope)

Comment: I find somethings. When I check status of other services by `svcs -x SERVICE_NAME` exp: `svcs -x system/system-log`. When I enable or disable any service, it must log like this `[ 2020 Jun 26 08:50:41 Enabled. ]` but there is nothing more in log file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what happened to the ssh service. I just reboot it. It work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to a service with forking child processes that are still running (which you want for an sshd restart!)

`svcs` would have showed it in maintenance state rather than online
`svcadm clear ssh` would have cleared the condition and actually started the new daemon.